# fn.bind is not a function

Tags: javascript, discord

I keep getting fh bind errors, I keep getting errors as I'm trying to assign roles on join with discord

```
client.on('guildMemberAdd', role => {
  console.log('user' + role.username + ' joined the battle!');
  var role = role.guild.roles.cache.find('name', 'member' )
  role.addrole(role)
});
```

Comment: Where is that error coming from?

Answer (score 3):

This is because you are using `role.guild.roles.cache.find` incorrectly.
According to [the manual](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/collection/master/class/Collection?scrollTo=find), this function works similar [to `Array.find` in JavaScript](https://cgi.cse.unsw.edu.au/~cs2041/doc/MDN_javascript_reference/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find.html).

The method takes a function that is supposed to return `true` for elements in the cache matching your search criteria, for example:

```
var role = role.guild.roles.cache.find(r => r.name === 'member');
```

Comment: You use `var` incorrectly, `const role` is the best declaration here.